# Reading file in assets folder in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, assets

I have a two-dimensional array of objects that I store in a file in the Assets folder of an Android Studio project. The file is serialized and named "maindata.conv"

Reading the file in Java is a breeze:

```
static public Object[][]  mainTable = null;

ObjectInputStream instream = new ObjectInputStream(getAssets().open("maindata.Conv"));

mainTable = (Object[][]) instream.readObject();
```

But when I translate the code to Kotlin, the translated code does not work:

```
val instream = ObjectInputStream(assets.open("maindata.Conv"))

MainActivity.mainTable = instream.readObject() as Array<Array<Any?>?>
```

The word "open" is flagged in red as "unresolved". Nothing I try to import works. How do I read a raw file in Kotlin from the Assets folder? Please help.

Comment: try `assets. \`open\`` instead of `assets.open` as `open` is a Kotlin keyword.

Comment: In Kotlin ``assets`` is just a shorthand for ``getAssets()`` which is a method on a ``Context`` - so if you call that inside an ``Activity`` it will just work. The Java code is the same so you must be calling it from a different place in the Kotlin version?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I found the root of my problem. I was trying to execute the Kotlin code from within a Java project. When I created a Kotlin project, the code works just fine. My guess is that it may have something to do with the context of the activity, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: You can mix and match Kotlin and Java in the same project - you just weren't calling ``assets`` on a ``Context`` (e.g. inside an activity instance). If you're getting a red underline it's because ``assets`` isn't a recognised property on whatever ``this`` is in your scope

Comment: Correct! Thanks! I'm still getting to know Kotlin.